# DNS: authorative vs. dynamic , can I have dynamic forward all requests to authorative nameservers

Tags: dns, web-hosting, nameservers, dyndns

Ok, in a nutshell, for my own reaons, I am trying to "build" a solution that extracts my DNS from the location / company where my webserver is located. I need to be able to make DNS changes on the fly for my domains. I have nameservers set-up for the webserver, on the webserver. I basically want to know if I can point my domain registration DNS details, to lets say, a DYN.com dynamic DNS address, and have that dynamic address setup to just forward all traffic onto my nameservers on the webserver.

This way, I can change the dyndns "pointer" if you will, to any other webserver/nameservers immedietly should the need arise.

P.S. I know a dynamic address probably won't work, and If I have to go for a paid up service with DYN, thats fine, but I don't want to create all the records on DYN. I just want it to forward any requests to the actual ip of the name server on the webserver.

I.E.

Domain NS1 -> Dyn.com Record 1 (no specific domain records) -> ns1.mywebserver.com

Domain NS2 -> Dyn.com Record 2 (no specific domain records) -> ns2.mywebserver.com

Can this be acieved, if not, do you get what I am trying to do, and are there other ways of doing this?

I ideally **don't** want to create a dedicated linux VM somewhere to manage the DNS.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: More a question for ServerFault?

Comment: Never been there.. :-) If needs be, can someone move it there?

Answer (score 0):

I think my other question, posted after this one, solves this question.

[BIND . Registrar says it cant find the nameserver. nslookup shows the domain is being handled by bind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11925338/bind-registrar-says-it-cant-find-the-nameserver-nslookup-shows-the-domain-is/11925475#11925475)

Cheers