# BIND . Registrar says it cant find the nameserver. nslookup shows the domain is being handled by bind

Tags: dns, bind, nameservers

I am new to BIND, and thought I had a grip on DNS, but obviously I was mistaken.

BIND is installed on Windows Server 2008 Web

1. I created a zone (`example.com`) with *Dyn*.
2. I registered the domain for that zone successfully, using the Dyn nameservers
3. I created two subdomains (A records) on the Dyn zone: `ns1.example.com` and `ns2.example.com`
4. Each subdomain points to a unique IP, bound to my server where BIND is listening

When I query `ns1.example.com` with `nslookup`, for the a new domain I created on that webserver, it returns `ns1` with its ip, but gives the following error:

```
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.

DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.

DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.

DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.

*** Request to ns1.example.com timed-out
```

If I run `nslookup` on the webserver itself, with the same query, I get:

```
> example.com

Server:  ns1.example.com (which is the slected nameserver)

Address:  xx.xx.xx.xx


Name:    example.com

Address:  xx.xx.xx.xx
```

It might be worth mentioning, that the Webserver is located in the UK, and I am located in South Africa.

My registrar, in South Africa, returns the following when I try to register `domainxyz.example`:

> The SOA record for domainxyz.example at xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx can not be retreived.
>   The most common reasons for this is that the Nameserver is not currently
>   reachable or the Nameserver has not been configured for this domain.

I can ping and resolve `ns1` and `ns2` from my pc, where the `nslookup` fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long discussion with myself, and curiously reviewing my post... I decided I must be really burnt out.. and I opened UDP port 53 on my windows firewall on the server.

Tadaaa.....works!

Sometimes it helps bouncing something off someone, even if its a lonely sunday night web page /forum.

Maybe this helps someone else in the future. This whole new web server commisioning has so many aspects to configure, and I lost site of the basics.

Cheers, and thanks..!